# Sigmoid going out of bound

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, floating-point, logistic-regression

```
def sigmoid(z):
# complete the code
z = np.asarray(z)
if z.ndim == 0:
    return(1/(1+np.exp(-z)))
else:
    d = np.array([])
    for item in z:
        d= np.append(d,1/(1+np.exp(-item)))
    return d
```

print(sigmoid([(1,3), (4,30)]))

why is this returning `[ 0.73105858  0.95257413  0.98201379  1.        ]`
as the function is bound from 0 to 1
for example `[q= 1/1+np.exp(-30)][1]` returns 1.0000000000000935

why is this happening and how to correct it?
 for example [image of a weird looking output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSSHN.png)

Comment: FYI: The logistic sigmoid function is implemented in SciPy as [`scipy.special.expit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sigmoid implementation looks fine.

The reason `print(1 / 1 + np.exp(-30))` returns `1.0000000000000935` is due to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

```
# Your example
1 / 1 + np.exp(-30)

# How it will be computed
(1 / 1) + np.exp(-30)

# What you actually wanted
1 / (1 + np.exp(-30))
```

P.S. numpy supports [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Your function can be simplified into:

```
def sigmoid(z):
    z = np.asarray(z)
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
```

Use [ravel](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) function to flatten the multi-dimensional array, if it's what you want.

Comment: But the sigmoid function is returning a value greater than 1, which is
[ 0.73105858  0.95257413  0.98201379  1.        ] 
the last output of this array is 1. something

Comment: It is rounded. The actual value is less than 1.

`sigmoid(np.array([20,3]))[0] < 1.0  ===>  True`

Answer (score 0):

oh BODMAS rule.

```
q= 1/(1+np.exp(-30))
```

returns `0.9999999999999065`

which is less than 1

It is rounded off to 1 in the console

Comment: But the sigmoid function is returning a value greater than 1, which is [ 0.73105858 0.95257413 0.98201379 1. ] the last output of array is 1. something